# Why does the static modifier prevent its variable to be reassigned with a new value?

Tags: c++, static, initialization, variable-assignment, modifiers

A minimal working example is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

void func()
{
    static int i = 5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    i = 42;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    std::cout << "this is main()" << std::endl;
    func();
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
this is main()
i is 5
i is 42
i is 42
i is 42
```

**Static** modifier for the variable **int** makes **int**'s value persistent for the life of the entire process while static storage is not stored on the stack; thus, the value is carried from one invocation of the function to another.

However, **int** is re-assigned to the value of 5 at the beginning of *func()* when *func()* is called second time.

So, why does this example output `i = 42` instead of `i = 5`?

Comment: Because static variables are only initialised once.

Comment: I was experimenting codes as a novice; but, I think you are right. I changed the question accordingly. I cannot upvote; therefore, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't. You have misinterpreted your evidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, int is re-assigned to the value of 5 at the beginning of func() when func() is called second time.

No, this is not [assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment), but [initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). [Static local variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) are initialized only once, i.e. when `func()` is called for the first time.

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have
>   static storage duration but are initialized the first time control
>   passes through their declaration (unless their initialization is zero-
>   or constant-initialization, which can be performed before the block is
>   first entered). On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely confused by the equals sign, `=`.

The equals sign in `static int i = 5;` means [copy initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), not assignment:

> The equals sign, **=**, in copy-initialization of a named variable is not
>   related to the assignment operator.

Thus,

> However, int is re-assigned to the value of 5 at the beginning of func()

This is wrong. It is **never assigned** at the beginning of `func`, neither the first time nor at later calls. It is *only* assigned by `i = 42;`.

You could have written the line like this, too:

```
static int i(5);
```